# Memoization of Dynamic Programming

Tags: java, dynamic-programming, memoization

I'm trying to learn Memoization of Dynamic Programming and I was watching video on youtube from MIT trying to follow along with it. I don't know how to compare the Nth value to an array.

```
int[] memo;
public int fib(int n) {
    int f = 0;

    if n is in memo then return memo[n] <----not sure how to code this line.

    if (n<=2) {
        f = 1;
    } else {
        f = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
    }

    memo[n] = f;
    return f;
}
```

Comment: are you alllowed to use **java API** ??

Comment: Note that the concept is called *memoization* (no "r"). I've edited your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing it with `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<Integer> memo = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public int fib(int n) {
    if (memo.size() == 0)
       memo.add(0); // element 0 is never accessed
    return fib2(n);
}

private int fib2(int n) {
    int f = 0;

    if (n < memo.size())
       return memo.get(n);

    if (n<=2) {
        f = 1;
    } else {
       f = fib2(n-2) + fib2(n-1);
    }

    memo.add(f); // elements inserted in order
    return f;
}
```

Doing it with array:

```
int[] memo;

public int fib(int n) {
    memo = new int[n+1]; // all initialized to 0
    return fib2(n);
}

private int fib2(int n) {
    int f = 0;

    if (memo[n] != 0)
       return memo[n];

    if (n <= 2) {
        f = 1;
    } else {
        f = fib2(n-2) + fib2(n-1);
    }

    memo[n] = f;
    return f;
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error with nullPointerException with your array. For the arraylist the number are coming out not right past fib(5).

Comment: @JavaStudent For array - You probably didn't have a second function such as `fib` above which constructs `memo` and calls the original function. For `ArrayList` - Seems to print correctly on my machine. Did you [check](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibtable.html) what the values should be?

Comment: Ok I see where my number did wrong. If I didn't add the memo.add(0), then after fib(6) the number would jump from 1,1,2,3,5,7,19,21,50. Why would we need to add(0) if we aren't going to use it?

Comment: @JavaStudent Because `memo.get(n) = fib(n)` (and `fib(0)` is 0 but never calculated or used with this algorithm). One could also remove `memo.add(0)` and have `memo[n-1] = fib(n)` (with applicable changes).

Comment: Your codes miss a `return` statement in the `fib` definition (you should have `return fib2(n);`). And the code with `array` declares an array not large enough (it should be of size `n+1`, and not just `n`).

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize your `memo` array with `-1` values since the algorithm will never insert`-1` in the array.

So checking if `memo[i]` has already been inserted means you have to check if `memo[i] != -1`.

*NB: the concept is actually called [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)*

Comment: Why not just leave it as the default value of 0? No initialized value in the array will ever be 0.

Comment: You can use `Arrays.fill` for this.

Comment: @Dukeling you can leave 0, but you usually actively set a dummy value, even if that value is 0 so that there is no ambiguity. It is especially useful if there is a bug in your algorithm or forgot a step.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare an array to a single element.

What you probably want is, supposing you have a -1 dummy value for uncomputed values:

`if (memo[n] != -1) return memo[n]`

Answer (score 0):

I like to use HashMap for Java. From my experience, HashMap makes Memoization really easy to implement. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Four Steps:

1. Get the base case
2. Using `m.get(n) == null` to check whether or not a sub-problem has been computed.
3. If (2) is not true, compute it recursively and store it to the HashMap.

   The **key** of the HashMap is the current sub-problems *identifier* (in the case of Fibonacci, it is the **n** of the **nth Fibonacci sequence**. 
   The **value** is the recursive call that solves the unsolved problem.
4. If (2) is true, return m.get(n).

Here is an Fibonacci example using the 4 steps:

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> memo = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();

int fib(int n) {

    //1. base case
    if (n <= 1) 
        return n; 

    //2. check if sub problem is computed yet.
    if (m.get(n) == null) {

        //3. if not, compute the sub problem.
        m.put(n, fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2));
    }

    //4. if so, return the result. 
    return m.get(n); 
}
```

You can the same exact approach for a lot of memoization problems.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, this question has 0 upvotes, but 4 answers, and I don't find any of them really satisfying. Here is an example of implementation + test using 4 different methods and comparing them:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Fib {

    // Straightforward implementation:
    public static int fib(int n) {
    if (n <= 1) {
        return n;
    }
    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
    }

    // Using array:
    static int[] memoArray;
    public static int fibArray(int n) {
    memoArray = new int[n];
    return fibArrayHelper(n);
    }
    private static int fibArrayHelper(int n) {
    if (n <= 1) {
        return n;
    } else {
        if (memoArray[n - 2] != 0) {
        return memoArray[n - 2];
        }
        memoArray[n - 2] = fibArrayHelper(n - 2) + fibArrayHelper(n - 1);
        return memoArray[n - 2];
    }
    }

    // Using ArrayList:
    static ArrayList < Integer > memoArrayList = new ArrayList < Integer > ();

    public static int fibArrayList(int n) {
    return fibArrayListHelper(n);
    }

    private static int fibArrayListHelper(int n) {
    if (n <= 1) {
        return n;
    } else {
        if (n - 2 < memoArrayList.size())
        return memoArrayList.get(n - 2);
        else {
        memoArrayList.add(fibArrayListHelper(n - 2) + fibArrayListHelper(n - 1));
        return memoArrayList.get(n - 2);
        }
    }
    }

    // Using HashMap:
    static HashMap < Integer, Integer > memoHash = new HashMap < Integer, Integer > ();

    static public int fibHashMap(int n) {
    if (n <= 1)
        return n;
    if (memoHash.get(n) == null) {
        memoHash.put(n - 2, fibHashMap(n - 1) + fibHashMap(n - 2));
    }
    return memoHash.get(n - 2);
    }


    public static void main(String args[]) {
    long preTime, postTime;
    int x = 35;

    preTime = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.printf("%17s: %d", "fib(" + x + ")", fib(x));
    postTime = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.printf(", computed in %10d nanoseconds.\n", postTime - preTime);

    preTime = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.printf("%17s: %d", "fibArray(" + x + ")", fibArray(x));
    postTime = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.printf(", computed in %10d nanoseconds.\n", postTime - preTime);

    preTime = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.printf("%17s: %d", "fibArrayList(" + x + ")", fibArrayList(x));
    postTime = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.printf(", computed in %10d nanoseconds.\n", postTime - preTime);

    preTime = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.printf("%17s: %d", "fibHashMap(" + x + ")", fibHashMap(x));
    postTime = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.printf(", computed in %10d nanoseconds.\n", postTime - preTime);
    }
}
```